# Custom NN architecture using Pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to make a custom CNN architecture using Pytorch. I want to have about the same control as what I would get if I make the architecture using numpy only.

I am new to Pytorch and would like to see some code samples of CNNs implemented without the nn.module class, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement `backward()` function in your custom class.

However from your question it is not clear whether

- your need just a new series of CNN block (so you better use nn.module and something like
  `nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d( ...)`  )
- you just need gradient descent  https://github.com/jcjohnson/pytorch-examples#pytorch-autograd , so computation backward on your own.

Comment: If I implement it using backward() will I be able to use the various included optimizers?

Comment: sure, wrap  it in  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()